# Is there any extension or tool available for Visual Studio for plotting of numerical data in debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plot, visual-studio-debugging

I am working with numerical data and I want to plot and analyze arrays and vectors in debug mode. I can plot data using intermediate window by using a third party's library and I am suppose to initialize object responsible of plotting and also I need to call few methods to visualize the data. I want to avoid it because when I have to plot several time then it is not effective. I would like to know that is there any extension or tool available  to visualize the numerical data in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a similar vein to the answer from Sergey Vlasov, there is another plugin for Visual Studio called [ArrayPlotter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2fde2c3c-5b83-4d2a-a71e-5fdd83ce6b96) that can plot arrays of type byte/short/int/float/double including interleaved and complex arrays.

It doesn't require you to modify the code to call the plotting routine. Any (practically) accessible memory can be treated as an array of the specified type and plotted whilst in a breakpoint in the debugger.

Disclaimer: I wrote the plugin

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Array Visualizer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eedc48e7-5169-40d3-b602-ad451990a420) extension: "Array Visualizer is a free, open source extension for visual studio. It is designed to display arrays (Jagged and up to 4D) while debugging an application."

Comment: It does not support used defined array type.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'used defined array type'?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you an Open source tool I been working on just for the same reason.

[HypnoLog](https://github.com/SimonLdj/hypnolog-server) can help you log any data from C# and visualize it as you wish. 
HypnoLog is very flexible tool, you can log any data structure and control its visualization.

Specifically for C# there is already a language wrapper, see [HypnoLog-CSharp](https://github.com/SimonLdj/hypnolog-csharp).
And for numerical arrays you can use the built-in visualization `plot`.

The only thing you need to add to your project is the `HypnoLog-CSharp` library. By default in C# HypnoLog will log only in `Debug` mode.

This is how it looks in C#:

```
HL.Log(new []{1, 2, 3}, "plot");
```

By the way, HypnoLog can be also used from any other language while using the same visualization.